# android app crawler not working locally via cl

Tags: android, android-studio, android-testing, firebase-test-lab, android-unit-testing

I am trying to run android app crawler: https://developer.android.com/training/testing/crawler

Also looked at this: https://android.jlelse.eu/test-robo-scripts-locally-useful-for-firebase-test-lab-pre-launch-reports-41da83d5769f

The problem is when I run the the crawler cl command: `java -jar crawl_launcher.jar --apk-file test.apk --android-sdk C:\Android\sdk` it simply hangs. It dont install the app.

It does recognize my connected device, if i remove the device it throws error.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

Try passing package name as well with the command

like `java -jar crawl_launcher.jar --apk-file test.apk --android-sdk C:\Android\sdk --app-package-name my.sample.project`

Answer (score 0):

Try on an emulator/device Android 9, api28. It didn't work on some devices.

https://medium.com/@denysiakimov/how-to-run-android-app-crawler-testing-tool-a0d6f387e89e